# In a Rails PWA, can I serve dynamic content in the manifest file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, manifest, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I have multiple subdomains, and I'd like to serve a different manifest file for each. I've found a few different sources claiming to accomplish this, but none of them work and most of the comments on them agree.

To start off with, I just had a normal manifest.json.erb file, and linked to it with `<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />`, and it worked fine.

1) So first, I tried just conditionally linking to different manifest files, like so:

```
<% if request.subdomain.include? "www" %>
  <link rel="manifest" href="/other-manifest.json" />
<% else %>
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
<% end %>
```

and then I would just add a file called other-manifest.json.erb. What's weird is that not only didn't this work for other-manifest.json.erb, but when the subdomain isn't "www", manifest.json.erb stopped working too. I still don't get why this is, because this shouldn't be any different than just linking to manifest.json, right?

I also tried just writing `<link rel="manifest" href="/other-manifest.json" />` and nothing else, and this didn't work either, which leads me to believe the file must be titled "manifest.json".

2) Other solutions involved omitting an href for the `rel=manifest` element and using Javascript to add it later on. Again, I don't know why this would work, but I gave it a shot:

```
    <link rel="manifest" id="manifest" />
    <!-- content -->
    <% if request.subdomain.include? "www" %>
        document.querySelector('#manifest').setAttribute('href', '/other-manifest.json');
    <% else %>
        document.querySelector('#manifest').setAttribute('href', '/manifest.json');
    <% end %>
```

but that didn't work either.

3) I also tried running `request.subdomain` inside the manifest.json.html file and conditionally rendering content based on that value, but that broke it too, which indicates the `request` object isn't accessible inside that file.

**Anyone succeed in rendering dynamic content in their manifest file?**

Comment: I'm not aware of any reason this shouldn't work. I would guess something else is causing the issue. Maybe caching issues?

Comment: @abraham Wait, so as far as you know, there's no reason I can't use a different name for manifest.json? That would solve all my problems if true. I don't think it's a caching issue because I've been using incognito windows, and it starts working as soon as I change the name back to manifest.json.

Answer (score 1):

The error I made was not adding the path of the new file to my precompile.

I added it to `config/initializers/assets.rb` like so:

```
Rails.configuration.assets.precompile += %w[serviceworker.js manifest.json austintacovan-manifest.json]
```

and now it conditionally serves two different manifests.